# How to demarcate data in a stacked area chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a stacked area chart that display data representing one of two states: the data on the bottom of the chart represents "approved" items, while data at the top represents "non-approved" items. The data has the same domain, so I ship it to d3 in a single array. Imagine that each entry in the array looks like the following:

```
item[n] = {
  datestamp: someValue, // (X-axis value)
  y: anotherValue, // (Y-axis value)
  approved: true
}
```

How I can demarcate the break between these two data sets (with a black line `path` element, for example)? That is, when my data set goes from `approved: true` to `approved: false`, I'd like to draw a line at that point, showing the break between the data.

Perhaps I figure out the final item with `approved: true`, then use those coordinates as the data given to the `path` element? I could probably compute that on the server side and ship it to my JavaScript via a bit of JSON, giving me something to key off of. Is there another way I'm missing?

**Update:** I can insert a dummy record into my data at the appropriate place (with values of 0), then style it using the following logic (the final two lines are the lines of interest):

```
var items = chart.selectAll(".item-chart")
    .data(myData)
    .enter()
    .append("g");

var areas = items.append("path")
    .attr("d", function(d) { return area(d.values); })
    .style("stroke", function(d) { if(d.name == "---") return "#000"; }
    .style("stroke-width", function(d) { if(d.name == "---") return "3px"; };
```

This feels wrong (I end up with a dummy entry in my chart legend), but it yields the look I want. Is there a way to simulate this behavior without actually inserting a dummy value?

**Update 2:** I have attached a screenshot of my chart. The thin black line near the top of the data is what I'd like to replicate, without having to insert a dummy value. I have also updated the sample item, to showcase that my x-axis is in reality a date stamp.

[image: Stacked area chart example]

Comment: What does your bar chart look like right now? Having trouble understanding your data model: if there are just approved-things and non-approved-things, wouldn't it make sense for each bar datapoint to just be `{approved::Number, notapproved::Number}`? If the `x` and `y` in the input data stand for coordinates, I don't understand how this bar chart works.

Comment: I've added a screenshot demonstrating what I'd like to do. The thin black line in the data is a dummy value (all zeros), and styled appropriately. Data above this line has the `approved` value set to false, data below the line has `approved` set to true. I'd like to duplicate this behavior without a dummy value in the data, but I can't figure out how to get the appropriate coordinates from the appropriate value in my data set.